# rstudio dplyr group _by multiple column

Tags: r, dplyr

In Rstudio, I have a dataframe which contains 4 columns and I need to get the list of every different triplet of the 3 first columns sorted decreasingly by the sum on the 4th column. For example, with:

```
A B C 2
D E F 5
A B C 4
G H I 5
D E F 3
```

I need as a result:

```
D E F 8
A B C 6
G H I 5
```

I've tried the following different approach but I can't manage to have exactly the result I need:

```
df_list<-df_raw_data %>%
group_by(param1, param2, param3) %>%
summarise_all(total = sum(param4))
arrange(df_list, desc(total))
```

and:

```
df_list<-unique(df_raw_data[, c('param1', 'param2', 'param3')])
cbind(df_list, total)

for(i in 1:nrow(df_raw_data))
{
 filter ???????????
}
```

I would prefer to use the dplyr package since it's a more elegant solution.

EDIT: Okay, thanks for your working answers. I think that I've lost some time figuring out that the plyr package shouldn't be loaded after dplyr...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_by_at` to select the columns to group.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-V4)) %>%
  summarise(V4 = sum(V4)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   V1    V2    V3       V4
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 A     B     C         6
# 2 D     E     F         8
# 3 G     H     I         5
```

Or use `group_by_if` to select columns to group based on column types.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by_if(is.character) %>%
  summarise(V4 = sum(V4)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   V1    V2    V3       V4
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 A     B     C         6
# 2 D     E     F         8
# 3 G     H     I         5
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A B C 2
D E F 5
A B C 4
G H I 5
D E F 3",
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this be what you are looking for?

```
df <- data_frame(var1 = c("A", "D", "A", "G", "D"),
             var2 = c("B", "E", "B", "H", "E"),
             var3 = c("C", "F", "C", "I", "F"),
             var4 = c(2, 5, 4, 5, 3))

df %>% group_by(var1, var2, var3) %>% 
       summarise(sum = sum(var4)) %>% 
       arrange(desc(sum))
```